# Tagging in rails with is_taggable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tagging

there is an example provided on how to add tags to a model with [is_taggable](http://github.com/jamesgolick/is_taggable), and it works very nice (working in 5 minutes)

Now, I also need the opposite, show all records that are tagged with a certain word.

Something like:

ModelWithTag.find_by_tags "foo"

or

find_all_tagged_with "foo"

Is this possible with is_taggable ?

Comment: just found out that there is another is_taggable plugin which works nicer:

http://github.com/karmi/is_taggable

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could do the following:

```
Tag.where(:name => 'english').first.taggings
```

which would get you the list of all items tagged with 'english'

Cheers,